# How do I scale in the sides of a cylinder without it getting distorted?

Tags: modeling, extrude

In this tutorial: ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbSmoZCrP8I&t=335s&index=2&list=WL ) Steve extrudes a circle and then scales in the sides after adding 2 edge cuts.

I have 2 questions.

1. How do you extrude a circle?
2. How do you scale in the sides? When I tried to scale in the sides, my cylinder gets distorted.

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask several separate questions. Also, I think it may be helpful to include screenshots of what the desired result is and what result you got from scaling your cylinder (that Youtube link might not always exist and it will mean people don't have to leave the site to see what you mean).

Answer (score 1):

He makes the following moves on a quarter of an octagon with subdivided edges, rotated by 45 in Z, mirrored in X and Y, Mirror modifier set to visible in Edit Mode. With Pivot set to 'Median'

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> Edge Loop, scroll wheel to make 2, Left-click to set, then Right-click to leave the loops where they were created.
- With the new loops selected in edge mode, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to spread them up and down evenly.
- He then switches to vertex-select mode, which implicitly selects the faces in the middle band
- At some point, he hits <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude that band of faces along their normals. It's all time-lapsed, so you can't say exactly when. He could have left it at that, but feels he needs to adjust the extruded faces by scaling them to the center.
- But now, look closely, he screws up. Scaling towards the Median of the quarter-circle doesn't work. It distorts his tower. He should be scaling to the center of the whole circle.
- So he undoes the scale, and switches his Pivot to 3D Cursor, which he has <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>put at the origin, and <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> scales the extruded band of faces in XY about the center of the tower.

Comment: Time-lapsed videos are maybe not the easiest way to learn basic moves. This tutorial is more of an overview, a general approach to getting stuff made.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, making a small circle inside the top of the cylinder then just select the vertices that make the top/Bottom and hit "I" to inset the faces.

As for scaling in the bits, I'd try Inset with that too, I don't know, it may or may not work. you should REALLY provide a screenshot.

If you find the little camera icon, click it to "Render active viewport."

Answer (score 0):

He makes it look easy!  That was also one of the first tutorials I watched.

To extrude the circle, select it (or the arc that remains, in his example) and use the [Extrude tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/extrude.html).  In his case, he used the mouse on the blue arrowhead to move it exactly in the proper axis.  Note that you can have the youtube player slow down the playback!  You can follow his exact movement at ¼ speed, I would think.

In the next sentence, he adds two edge cuts.  I know the Ctrl-R tool does this, but I’ve not gotten it to do two at once symmetric from the center like he did — various modifiers to control that, and the mouse wheel to change the number of cuts.  Adding one at a time accomplishes the same thing.

When he did that, the faces bounded by the new edges were selected already.  If that’s not the case, go to face-select mode and select just those faces (and only those).  Now use the Scale tool (press S or use the toolbar) and it will change the radius of that section of wall but not affect the ends (which are not selected).

You might try a basic tools tutorial first, and then come back to this.  He makes extensive use of Inset and Scale, selecting entire loops at once, and adding loop cuts.